# Python mysql-connector commit not working

Tags: python, mysql, commit, python-multithreading

So I've been at it for hours, and there is something really weird going on.

I am looping through code to check if a table value has changed. And if so run some code.

When i run the following program everything works totally fine! The 'lock state' goes from Open to Closed as it should be doing.

```
    import time
    import mysql.connector

    host = '...'
    database = '...'
    user = '...'
    password = '...'

    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=host, database=database, user=user, password=password)
    conn.start_transaction(isolation_level='READ COMMITTED')

    state = 'Open'

    def get_web_lock_request():
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `doorlock`.`state`")
            state = ''.join(cursor.fetchone())
            cursor.close()
            return state
        except mysql.connector.Error as e:
            print 'get_lock_state ' + format(e)
            return ''

    def set_web_lock_request():
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("UPDATE `doorlock`.`state` SET `state`='" + state + "'")
            conn.commit()
            cursor.close()
        except mysql.connector.Error as e:
            print 'set_lock_state: ' + format(e)

    while 1:
        dbstate = get_web_lock_request()
        set_web_lock_request()

        if state == 'Open':
            state = 'Closed'
        else:
            state = 'Open'

        time.sleep(2)
        print dbstate
```

But in my main code this 'listening for a change' is in a thread. And for some reason the UPDATE statement does not work! even with the conn.commit()

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=host, database=database, user=user, password=password)
conn.start_transaction(isolation_level='READ COMMITTED')

def get_web_lock_request():
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `doorlock`.`state`")
        state = ''.join(cursor.fetchone())
        cursor.close()
        return state
    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print 'get_lock_state ' + format(e)
        return ''

def set_web_lock_request(state):
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("UPDATE `doorlock`.`state` SET `state`='" + state + "'")
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print 'set_lock_state: ' + format(e)

def web_request_listener():
    global updating
    try:
        while 1:

            print 'get_web_lock_request : ' + get_web_lock_request()
            print 'current_state : ' + current_state()

            if get_web_lock_request() != current_state() and not updating:
                if get_web_lock_request() == 'Open':
                    open_lock()
                    print 'DoorLock: State is now open'
                elif get_web_lock_request() == 'Closed':
                    close_lock()
                    print 'DoorLock: State is now closed'

            time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()

if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        button_listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=button_listener)
        web_request_listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=web_request_listener)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

I could really use some help, I have literallyhave nothing else to try :)

Floris